# api node .js (posting data to mailchimp server via api)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting this error when i run my program

**Error:**

> ReferenceError: option is not defined
> at C:\Users\H00422000\desktop\newsletter-signup\app.js:39:33
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\H00422000\desktop\newsletter-signup\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (C:\Users\H00422000\desktop\newsletter-signup\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\H00422000\desktop\newsletter-signup\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\H00422000\desktop\newsletter-signup\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at C:\Users\H00422000\desktop\newsletter-signup\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (C:\Users\H00422000\desktop\newsletter-signup\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
> at next (C:\Users\H00422000\desktop\newsletter-signup\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at serveStatic (C:\Users\H00422000\desktop\newsletter-signup\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\H00422000\desktop\newsletter-signup\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

**Code:**

```
const express=require("express");
const request=require("request");
const app=express();
const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
const https=require("https");


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname +"/news.html");
});
app.post("/",function(req,res){
var f1=req.body.f1;
var l1=req.body.l1;
var e1=req.body.e1;

var data={
  members: [
    {
      email_address:e1,
      status:"subscribed",
      merge_feilds:{
        FNAME:f1,
        LNAME:l1
      }
    }
  ]

};
const url='https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/f0c448a295';
const options = {
  method: "post",
  auth:"mihr:229d66f728411db957eaae8894911467-us10"
}


const jsonData=JSON.stringify(data);
const request=https.request(url,option,function(response){

if (res.statusCode===200)
{res.send("suceeedede")}
else{res.send("errororrrororo")}

response.on("data",function(data){
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});


});

request.write(jsonData);
request.end();

//229d66f728411db957eaae8894911467-us10
//f0c448a295
});


app.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log("server is running on 3000 port")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you made a small typo:

```
const request=https.request(url,options,function(response){

if (res.statusCode===200)
{res.send("suceeedede")}
else{res.send("errororrrororo")}

response.on("data",function(data){
  console.log(JSON.parse(data));
});


});
```

this should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

You declare a variable as `options` but reference it as `option` so it will throw an error of `option is not defined`

```
const request=https.request(url,options,function(response){})
```